# Can I Get the indirect reportees through microsoft graph api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I refered few of the references I couldn't able to find an api to get indirect reportees.

These are the things I referred

[Direct reportees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-directreports?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript)

[Indirect reportees using powershell](https://lazywinadmin.com/2014/10/powershell-who-reports-to-whom-active.html)

Can any one guide me on this how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

Getting indirect reporters through Microsoft Graph API is not currently supported.
If you want to get indirect reporters through Microsoft API,you should request the current user's direct reporter, and then make the same request for all of the resulting direct reporters...

```
GET /me/directReports
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/directReports
```